# Hanging objects on wood panel mantle

Tags: fireplace, studs, hanging, paneling

I have a house built in 1957 and in the living room is a fireplace with wood paneling mantle. This is my first home and am not sure what is behind the wood paneling and what it can support. I'd like to hang a heavier mirror, or maybe a TV down the road.

I have drilled where my studfinder indicated there was a stud but have come up empty handed so far. Any ideas on what to expect behind the paneling without drilling a bunch of holes, or how to safely hang something in the 45-60lbs range would be super helpful to this first time DIYer!
[image: fireplace & mantle]

Comment: Where exactly did you attempt to use your stud-finder? If you were scanning over the paneling then that's likely the problem - try scanning the bare wall above the paneling instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info that is probably why! Unfortunately my paneling goes all the way up to the ceiling, with a moulding strip around the top. Appreciate your insight!

Comment: In that case my next-best suggestion would be to get an inexpensive borescope and drill a large-enough hole (maybe 3/4") all the way through the paneling & wall, positioned in a spot which you know will be covered by whatever you're hanging, so that you can see inside and get a reasonable estimate of where the framing is.

Comment: If the walls are plaster the studfinder may be worthless there too.